# Logging method name , input parameters , date and time with using Attribute

Tags: datetime, logging, methods, attributes

i just want to make a class that inherited from Attribute class to put attribute tags in every method in my project to write the method name , Class name that have this method , date and time of calling , parameters and method's return ( if it's return something ).

i create a table in SQL Server that will receive all log information and sign it ..

i have done all the methods & query that interact with my database ( except Date & Time method)  , the only problem is i don't know how to use it with Attribute way to get the information i have mention.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516769/using-c-sharp-custom-attributes-for-exception-and-audit-trail-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want logging with attributes, you may use PostSharp that modifies IL during compilation of your code and puts your logging codes before/after the method that you put your custom attribute derived from PostSharp's attributes (aspects)(AOP).

I think you can not do this only by use of custom attributes, because as I know custom attributes are instantiated only when `Type.GetCustomAttributes()` is called. So you may have to do some reflection business for sending your logs through your attributes that I don't recommend.

Instead of attributes, you can simply use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) through a third party tool. You can use [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy-Introduction.ashx) 's interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also log with attributes by using Interception in Castle Windsor.

To do this, you create a class that inherits from `IInterceptor`, register it with your container, then you can add an attribute to any class or method you want to add the logging behaviour to.

I've written an explanation here:
http://www.paulsodimu.co.uk/Post/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Castle-Windsor

And I've created a sample on GitHub to show how its done:
https://github.com/PaulSodimu/LoggingAopCastle